# dynamic href id tags with Jquery Tipsy plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to get the tipsy plugin working and can't seem to do it with dynamic id's.
this is the code I was trying to use.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery("a#[id^='pro_']").each(function(){
        jQuery("a#[id^='pro_']").tipsy({gravity: jQuery.fn.tipsy.autoNS,live: 'true'});
    });
});
```

a link would look someting like `<a id="pro_1" title="some value" href="link.html">My Link</a>`

Not sure if the jquery is correct but I tried it several ways.
Thanks

Comment: I figured it out. This works by itself.  jQuery("a#[id^='pro_']").tipsy({gravity: jQuery.fn.tipsy.autoNS,live: 'true'});

Answer (score 0):

The selector is incorrect. You don't need the "#" there. Just use `$('a[id^=pro_]')`. The hash sign (#) means the same as `[id=…]`, so it doesn't make sense to use both it and `[id^=…]`.

Comment: Actually it will work either way, but I found my mistake. It was a typo and also using the each function is not necessary with this plugin. Thanks for the response anyway.